# C - How to more easily point to the beginning of an array of strings using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, data-structures

I have a function. This function is designed to iterate through customer names in an array of structures referred to as a customer accounts receivable database. The code uses pointers to reference the array of structures to access each customer name at each index in the database. The code is supposed to clear all nonletter characters and then titlecase the first letter of each name.

```
/**********************************************************************/
/*     Titlecases and removes all nonletter characters from names     */
/**********************************************************************/
void clean_names(struct customer *p_customer_start, int customer_number)
{
   struct customer *p_last_name; /* Points to every customer          */
   char *p_fast,                 /* Points to customer's name         */
        *p_slow;                 /* Points to all letters             */

   for(p_last_name = p_customer_start;
      (p_last_name - p_customer_start) < customer_number; p_last_name++)
   {
      p_fast = p_last_name->last_name;
      p_slow = p_last_name->last_name;

      while(*p_fast != END_OF_STRING)
      {
         if(isalpha(*p_fast))
            *p_slow++ = tolower(*p_fast);
         p_fast++;
      }
      *p_slow = END_OF_STRING;
      *(p_slow-strlen(p_last_name->last_name)) =
      toupper(*(p_slow-strlen(p_last_name->last_name)));
   }
   return;
}
```

I'm having a hard time with the line

```
*(p_slow-strlen(p_last_name->last_name)) = toupper(*(p_slow-strlen(p_last_name->last_name)));
```

the `struct customer` has an array of characters `char  last_name[21]`. I'm having trouble using pointers to point to the first item in the array of characters and capitalizing it. The method I'm using is the only solution I've found that works. `p_slow` points at the NULL character at the end of the string. I use pointer arithmetic to dereference `p_slow - total string length` using strlen() to make it point to the first item in the array `p_last_name->last_name`.

I'm not looking for a clearly laid out solution, I'm just looking for suggestions to streamline the code.

Comment: Do you have to do this with pointer arithmetic? Just access `p_customer_start` as an array.

Comment: It has to be with pointer arithmetic. No indexes are to be used.

Comment: For any pointer or array `p` and *index* `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. So when you do `*(p_slow-strlen(p_last_name->last_name)` that's the same as `p_slow[-strlen(p_last_name->last_name)]`. I,e, `-strlen(p_last_name->last_name)` is used exactly like an array index.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude He's only using `strlen()` to index within a single string, not when addressing the whole structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that complex expression to find the first character of the name. `p_last_name->last_name` contains the updated name, so you can just deference that to access the first character.

```
*p_last_name->last_name = toupper(*p_last_name->last_name);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. I'm just really dumb. I emailed my instructor two questions about this series of code, and he answered only the other question. This post was the second question.